# How can I update Angular component with observable or subject in Storybook?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, storybook, angular-storybook

I want to use a subject to update my Angular component, but it's not work when I call `subject.next(false)` in Storybook. The property of component instance has updated but not work for canvas panel.

I have a loading component like this

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-loading',
    templateUrl: './loading.component.html'
})
export class LoadingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestory {
    // control the loading icon show or not
    public state: boolean = true;
    private subscription: Subscription = null;

    constructor(private loadingSerivce: LoadingService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.subscription = this.loadingService.state.subscribe(state => {
            this.updateState(state);
            console.log(this.state);
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if (this.subscription) {
            this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }

    updateState(state: boolean): void {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

and the loading service like this

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoadingService {
    public state: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
}
```

and the loading stories like this

```js
@Injectable({
    prividedIn: 'root'
})
class MockLoadingService extends LoadingService {
    static instance: MockLoadingService = null;

    constructor() {
        super();

        if (!MockLoadingService.instance) {
            MockLoadingService.instance = this;
        }

        return MockLoadingService.instance;
    } 
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-loading',
    templateUrl: './loading.component.html',
})
class MockLoadingComponent extends LoadingComponent {
    constructor(private mockLoadingService: MockLoadingService) {
        super(mockLoadingService);
    }
}

export default {
    title: 'Loading',
    component: MockLoadingComponent,
    decorators: [
        moduleMetadata({
            declarations: [MockLoadingComponent],
            providers: [MockLoadingService],
        }),
    ],
} as Meta;

export const Loading: Story = props => ({ props });

Loading.play = async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            MockLoadingService.instance.state.next(false);
            resolve(null);
        }, 2000);
    });
};
```

The question is: after `npm run storybook`, I can get the state is `false`, but the loading icon in canvas panel still showing. So how can I update the Angular component with observable or subject in Storybook?

---

additional remarks
loading.component.html

```html
<div *ngIf="state" class="loading" id="loading">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="25 25 50 50" class="circular">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" class="path"></circle>
    </svg>
</div>
```

And it works like this

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.loadingService.state.subscribe(state => {
        this.updateState(state);
        console.log(this.state);
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.loadingService.state.next(false);
    }, 1000);
}
```

just not work in storybook play function

Comment: Did you check the ```this.loadingService.state.subscribe()``` statement subscribing or not? and check the next event as well ```MockLoadingService.instance.state.next(false);```

Comment: @Yaseer the `console.log()` has been called, and output `false`

Comment: I hope you have added correct condition in the loading html ```loading.component.html```

Comment: @Yaseer i have added `loading.component.html` in the question

Comment: You need to implement your LoadingService, at the moment it's not doing anything. And you have two "state" variables (one in the component, the other in the service) which is also not very helping

Comment: @wiwi it works when state.next call in component, but not works in storybook

Comment: @coderben that's what I was partially talking about. The "next" instruction should be implemented in the service, not the component, and the service only should hold the state, in one and only single place. Then you could call and use the service's method inside any component (after passing a private instance of the service to the its constructor)

Comment: Please look into the storybook docs, I feel your config is wrong https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/angular/en/simple-component/

Answer (score 0):

Your subscription is subscribed to the incorrect service?
Your component loads an instance of `LoadingService` and subscribes to that

```
this.loadingService.state.subscribe
```

yet the `next` statement is triggered on an instance of `MockLoadingService`?

```
MockLoadingService.instance.state.next(false);
```

Those two are not the same service despite one extending the other?

so solution, either use the `MockLoadingService` in the component constructor or trigger the `next` call on the `LoadingService` class instead of on the `MockLoadingService` class?